# What would be the best way to download a list of files from a server?

Tags: ftp, download, wget

I have a list of SWF files that I want to download to my PC. Is there a quick way to do this from my server, like using WGET or something similar. Each file line list is a new line:

```
http://super.xx-cdn.com/730_silvxxxen/v/v.swf
http://super.xx-cdn.com/730_sixxxxheen/73xxxxversheen.swf
http://super.xx-cdn.com/730_rxxxd/v/v.swf
```

There are thousands of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ssh over putty to access your server you could easily use `winscp` from putty

otherwise you could also use `pscp`

If you do not have putty installed get it and make up a ssh to your server

Another easy way to download them is just getting an `FTP client` and download them over FTP

Comment: I also used - http://superuser.com/questions/202466/how-do-i-make-httrack-download-at-15mbps

Comment: The reason for WinHTTPTrack was simple to link to .html file and then it just grabs off this.

Comment: Yeah that's an valid alternative also :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple SH script, if I correctly understand your question:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
    wget $line
done < "urls.txt"
```